# Game Development - Array with pointers to array elements

Tags: arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am currently developing a game for the iPhone/iPod/iPad.  To store the board data, which is 12 columns by 8 rows, I have an array that stores pointers to one of the game items, a block.  It is declared as follows:

```
BlockData* mBoard[kNumberOfColumns][kNumberOfRows];
```

I also have another array declared like this:

```
BlockData* mCenterSquare[16];
```

This I want to store pointers to specific locations on the board, for example,

```
mCenterSquare[0] = mBoard[4][5];
```

Is this the right way of doing it?  What I want to accomplish using the above line of code is for mCenterSquare[0] to store a pointer to a position on the board - 4th column and 5th row.  How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not only use the mCenterSquare array to store data:

```
function BlockData* getBlockData(int row, int col) {
     return mCenterSquare[row * kNumberOfCols + col]
}
```

Comment: Whate does row * kNumberOfCols + col supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but think this is a trick question.  Yes, that is the way you would do it. :)

Comment: It doesn't compile though . . .

Comment: @macdude93: It is legal syntax (and it compiles for me).  Is BlockData a typedef?  What is the compilation error you are getting?

Comment: My mistake - I feel stupid.  There wasn't a ; after the last statement.  Ridiculous.  I didn't even look at the error before posting this.  Had to have been tired.